# iOS - Keep background animation across view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a basic UINavigationController design for the settings pages of an app.  Each settings page is its own view controller (with xib), and each page has the same background image.

I've since built a view-based animation to replace the background image, and I'd like it to play uninterrupted while the user moves from page to page.  In other words, it's as though each settings page had a transparent background, and beneath all of them was a single instance of my animating view.

How would I go about doing this?

So far, I've tried just putting the animation on each page separately, but the transitions look a bit too sloppy for me.  I'd also considered somehow having a single UIView with all necessary animations underneath my navigation controller, but not sure a) if that's feasible, and b) how to go about that.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to be using "Container View Controllers"

You can read up on the Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

---

The solution would be to have one master view controller which holds onto your settings view controllers. The settings view controllers background is transparent so you see the background of the master view controller.

As for the animation see `Listing 14-3  Transitioning between two view controllers` on the link I provided you.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I ended up putting my animation code into a custom UINavigationController (I suppose a sort of Container View Controller?) and then setting the background to all my UIViewControllers to transparent, which appears to do the trick!

Comment: You shouldn't subclass UINavigationController if you are targeting anything under iOS 6. but yes, navigation controller just holds container view controllers

Comment: OK, good to know.  Why shouldn't it be subclassed for older OSs?

Comment: Read the last sentence of the first paragraph on `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html` ... `This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later.`

Comment: Its undocumented behaviour and could lead to red herrings in your code, best to stick to what apple supports to have yourself a headache later on down the line.